# Laravel (or PHP) - easy & simple back up of Postgres DB

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel

Is there an easy way to back up a Postgres DB via PHP (I'm using Laravel)?

When using MySQL, I found quite a simple script that will dump all the tables into a single file, but haven't been able to find something similar for Postgres. I found a few libraries (packages), but wanted to know if someone had a simple script that did this.

Comment: I use this - https://github.com/heybigname/backup-manager

Comment: `pg_dump`? Isn't it pretty simple to invoke shell commands from PHP? Not getting what's complicated here. For max simplicitly, even `pg_dumpall`.